# Create Thresholds on windows form based on Dataset Values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dataset

Update, I've been trying to understand @Plutonix idea, but I'm not being able to put it into practice therefore haven't been able to achieve a resolution for my problem.

Can someone give me some help on how to put @Plutonix idea into place? or any other idea that will result in the same goal.

I simply want to create a set of Conditional statements for each row on my dataset and I want those conditional statements to populate the boxes shown below.

-----------------------------//----------------------------------

I'm creating a windows application with an access database behind it.

This access database contains 5 columns and 40 rows.

The first Column is the ID of the row, the second column its the person's name and the remaining 3 columns are grades from 1 to 25.

In my form my objective is to have a box with the person's name and smaller boxes inside with the grade, and I want this boxes to have a threshold that makes them change back colour based on the grade. This is all easy to do and I've done the first 2 boxes with if statements based on a value found on a textbox with the grade.

My problem is, there are 40 Rows, this means I will have to do several if statements with several conditions to EACH ONE of the students and this will result in 120 sets of code.

Now...bear in mind I'm not usually a programmer therefore my technical knowledge is limited, but how do I define the thresholds in a easier way for all of my dataset taking into account the thresholds are the same for everyone? I don't want to do an if statement for each threshold/column/person.

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
If (Me.PersonBox1.Text < 17) Then

        Me.Contract2.BackColor = Color.Crimson
        Me.Label4.BackColor = Color.Crimson
        Me.TextBox4.ForeColor = Color.White
        Me.Label5.BackColor = Color.Crimson
        Me.TextBox4.BackColor = Color.Crimson

    ElseIf (Me.PersonBox1.Text>= 17 And Me.TextBox1.Text <= 18) Then

        Me.Contract2.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Me.Label4.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Me.TextBox4.ForeColor = Color.White
        Me.Label5.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Me.TextBox4.BackColor = Color.Orange

    ElseIf (Me.PersonBox1.Text >= 19 And Me.TextBox1.Text <= 20) Then

        Me.Contract2.BackColor = Color.Gold
        Me.Label4.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Me.TextBox4.ForeColor = Color.White
        Me.Label5.BackColor = Color.Gold
        Me.TextBox4.BackColor = Color.Gold

    ElseIf (Me.PersonBox1.Text >= 21 And Me.TextBox1.Text <= 22) Then

        Me.Contract2.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
        Me.TextBox4.ForeColor = Color.White
        Me.Label5.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
        Me.TextBox4.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen

    ElseIf (Me.PersonBox1.Text > 22) Then

        Me.Contract2.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Me.TextBox4.ForeColor = Color.White
        Me.Label5.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Me.TextBox4.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Me.Label5.ForeColor = Color.White


    End If
```

Now I don't want to repeat this 120 times per student per column so now my mind is pushing me this way:

```
Dim Var_OStatus As Integer
    Dim Var_SlaAch As Integer
    Dim Var_Com As Integer
    Dim Var_Part As Integer
    Dim Var_ContImp As Integer
    Dim Var_OStab As Integer
    Dim Var_PersonID As Integer
    Dim table As DataTable
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim column As DataColumn
    For Each table In Contract_ManagementDataSet3.Tables
        For Each row In table.Rows
            For Each column In table.Columns
                Var_OStatus = Contract_ManagementDataSet3.Tables(0).Rows(0).ToString

                MsgBox("test   " + Var_OStatus.ToString())
            Next column
        Next row
    Next table
```

I think this might be the way to go but I'm absolutely lost now.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Example of Dashboard:

Each square will change its colour according to the values in it based on a general threshold:

[image]

Regards

Comment: You should start by putting `Option Strict On` at the top of the code file.

Comment: If you have 40 rows, you will have 40 sets of those controls? In general, it seems like a DataGridView would be easier and less code.

Comment: Yes 40 Boxes and within those 40 boxes 3 boxes for each grade. Datagridview is not an option at least on this form as I'm trying to create a smart-ish looking dashboard.

Comment: How will the Option Strict On affect the code?

Comment: Then you may want to research *databinding* and *UserControl*...or write lots of code just like that.  Option Strict will force you to write better code

Comment: @Plutonix Right, I was looking into databinding, it seems databinding will bind whatever data you decide from your dataset into your chosen box. Can't understand how this will help me defining the common thresholds for all the rows in the table. Can you give me an idea on how to do so?

Comment: You already have the range brackets - the problem is repeating the code for 40 rows, no?  A UserControl could prevent the repeated code - although I have no idea what a "smart dashboard" looks like, nor what this data is.  I am not sure that 40 or so UCs scrolling down the form is any cleaner or "smarter" than A DGV though

Comment: Updated with an example of what it is suppose to look like

Comment: Definitely a UserControl, then place them on a FlowLayOut panel. Pass the Data via a method interface.  All the code to do the colors is there just once